# Memory Leak due to Snackbar

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I´ve just added CanaryLeak to my project to see if there are any memory leaks in my application and noticed, that there is indeed a leak in one my fragments due to a Snackbar.

I´m creating a Snackbar in the `onCreateView` and set it to `null` in `onDestroyView`. However I get a memory leak every time I rotate the screen.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
    container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_backend, container, 
        false);

        Activity parentActivity = getActivity();
        if (parentActivity != null) {
            mConnectSnackbar = 
            Snackbar.make(parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment), 
            "Connect", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

            mConnectSnackbar.setAction(getString(R.string.connect), v -> 
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)));
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mConnectSnackbar.setAction("Connect", null);
        mConnectSnackbar.dismiss();
        mConnectSnackbar = null;
    }
```

As I clear the reference to the action and the Snackbar itself there shouldn´t be any reason for a memory leak. However I can´t figure out, what the reason might be and the Heap Dump from Canary Leak doesn´t help either.
I have a suspicion that it might me due to the reference to the nav_host_fragment, but I don´t know if it´s true and how to fix it.

Many Thanks for your help.

### Edit 1:

Added Leak Trace and removed hprof file.

```
┬
├─ android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static AccessibilityManager.sInstance
│                                  ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ AccessibilityManager.mTouchExplorationStateChangeListeners
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.ArrayMap
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
│               ~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array Object[].[4]
│                     ~~~
├─ androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerWrapper
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ AccessibilityManagerCompat$TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerWrapper.mListener
│                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar$SnackbarBaseLayout$1
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ BaseTransientBottomBar$SnackbarBaseLayout$1.this$0
│                                                  ~~~~~~
╰→ com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
​     Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
​     mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.twaice.twaice.MainActivity with mDestroyed = true
​     View#mParent is null
​     View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a memory leak in the material-components-android library. I just filed an issue: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/497

This leak only happens if a snackbar is created but never shown as described in the issue:

> In Material Library 1.0.0, when a BaseTransientBottomBar .SnackbarBaseLayout instance is created, it registers a TouchExplorationStateChangeListener which it then unregisters onDetachedFromWindow(). If the SnackbarBaseLayout is created but never attached (which happens), then it never gets detached. When the underlying context (an activity) gets destroyed, the TouchExplorationStateChangeListener is kept in memory by AccessibilityManager, holding on to its outer class SnackbarBaseLayout which itself holds on to its context, a destroyed activity. Effectively SnackbarBaseLayout is leaking destroyed activities and the entire view hierarchy.

The good news is that this code no longer exists in the 1.1.0 releases, so the leak is gone, though unfortunately 1.1.0 is still in alpha release.

Note: in future posts, consider providing the text leaktrace that LeakCanary outputs, which is useful to solve a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your insights and creating the issue on GitHub. I will consider switching to 1.1.0, even though I´m normally not a huge fan of alpha releases.

And thanks for the note; I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: This is an androidx library...How to fix this in a project which is not moved to androidx ??

Answer (score 0):

I think I´ve managed to find a solution, even though I don´t understand the reason for it. As stated, I´ve create the Snackbar in `onCreateView` but some other logic later decides whether the Snackbar is shown or not.

Now to the solution: The memory leak only exists when the Snackbar is created but never shown. So instead of creating the Snackbar in the `onCreateView` I´ve put the following code in the function that is called when the Snackbar should be shown:

```
if (mConnectSnackbar == null) {
        Activity parentActivity = getActivity();
        if (parentActivity != null) {
            mConnectSnackbar = 
            Snackbar.make(parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment), 
            "Connect", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

            mConnectSnackbar.setAction(getString(R.string.connect), v -> 
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)));
            mConnectSnackbar.show()
        }
} else {
       mConnectSnackbar.show();
}
```

Since I´ve added this change no memory leak has occured. However I don´t really understand why it occured when `show()` isn't called. I would really appreciate if someone can give some insight why this happens.